# SWIFT - TableViewController Segue to another TableViewController based on row selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a TableViewController (lets called TVC1) with three rows - OD, Weight, ID

When one of the three is selected, it will segue to another TableViewController (TVC2) to show the user the options available for selection. No matter what row is selected from TVC1, it will always segue to TVC2. So i'm going to be using enum so i can change the options available to the user based on their selection. However, when I run the app, i get a crash that says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" and it points to the line `view2.selectedData = selectedOption` in my TVC1 code

My code for TVC2 is:

```
import UIKit

enum Data {
case OuterDiameter
case Weight
case InnerDiameter
}

class CasingSelectionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedData = Data.OuterDiameter

let casingOD = ["114.3", "127.0", "139.7", "168.3" , "177.8", "193.7", "219.1", "244.5", "247.6", "273.1", "298.4", "298.4", "339.7", "406.4", "473.0", "508"]

let casingWeight114 = ["14.14", "15.63", "17.26", "20.09", "22.47", "24.70", "26.34", "27.97"]
let casingWeight127 = ["17.11", "19.35", "22.32", "26.79", "31.85", "34.53", "35.86"]
let casingWeight139 = ["20.83", "23.07", "25.30", "29.76", "34.23", "39.28", "44.20", "48.51", "52.53", "56.55", "60.27", "64.14"]
let casingWeight168 = ["19.34", "25.30", "29.76", "32.74", "35.71", "38.69", "41.66", "43.15", "47.62", "50.59"]
let casingWeight177 = ["25.30", "29.76", "34.23", "38.69", "43.16", "47.62", "52.09", "56.55"]
let casingWeight193 = ["35.72", "39.29", "44.20", "50.15", "58.04"]
let casingWeight219 = ["35.72", "41.67", "47.62", "53.57", "59.53"]
let casingWeight244 = ["48.07", "53.57", "59.53", "64.73", "69.94", "79.62"]
let casingWeight247 = ["88.09"]
let casingWeight273 = ["48.74", "60.27", "67.71", "75.90", "82.59"]
let casingWeight298 = ["56.54", "62.50", "69.94", "80.35", "89.28", "96.72", "105.65"]
let casingWeight339 = ["71.43", "81.10", "90.78", "101.19", "107.15"]
let casingWeight406 = ["96.73", "111.61", "125.01", "162.21"]
let casingWeight473 = ["108.76", "116.06", "130.00", "143.59"]
let casingWeight508 = ["139.89", "158.49", "197.93"]

let id114 = ["103.886", "102.921", "101.600", "99.568", "97.180", "95.300", "93.900", "92.400"]
let id127 = ["115.824", "114.148", "111.963", "108.610", "104.800", "104.800", "102.718", "101.600"]
let id139 = ["127.305", "125.730", "124.257", "121.361", "118.618", "114.300", "111.150", "107.950", "104.800", "101.600", "98.450", "95.520"]
let id168 = ["158.800", "155.800", "153.600", "152.100", "150.300", "148.700", "147.000", "146.300", "144.100", "142.100"]
let id177 = ["166.065", "163.982", "161.696", "159.410", "157.074", "154.788", "152.502", "150.368"]
let id193 = ["178.400", "177.000", "174.700", "171.900", "168.300"]
let id219 = ["205.664", "203.632", "201.193", "198.700", "197.400"]
let id244 = ["228.630", "226.590", "224.410", "222.380", "220.500", "216.790"]
let id247 = ["217.400"]
let id273 = ["258.877", "255.270", "252.730", "250.190", "247.904"]
let id298 = ["283.200", "281.500", "279.400", "276.300", "273.600", "271.300", "268.800"]
let id339 = ["322.961", "320.421", "317.881", "315.341", "313.614"]
let id406 = ["387.350", "384.150", "381.254", "373.075"]
let id473 = ["454.000", "453.500", "450.900", "448.400"]
let id508 = ["485.750", "482.600", "475.742"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    switch selectedData {

    case .OuterDiameter:
        print(casingOD)

    case .Weight:
        print(casingWeight114)

    case .InnerDiameter:
        print(id114)

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}
```

and my code in TVC1 is:

```
import UIKit

class CapacitiesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedOption: Data!
let capacityParameters = ["O.D", "Weight", "I.D"]

@IBAction func cancelSelection(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 125.0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return capacityParameters.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // init return type of cell
    var returnCell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.section == 0 { // you can also check for section with section.index
        returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("capacitiesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let capacityID = capacityParameters[indexPath.row]
        returnCell.textLabel?.text = capacityID

    return returnCell

    } else {

        returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return returnCell

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        selectedOption = Data.OuterDiameter
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        selectedOption = Data.Weight
    } else {
        selectedOption = Data.InnerDiameter
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("capacitiesSelectedSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destinationView = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
      let view2 = destinationView.topViewController as! CasingSelectionTableViewController
        view2.selectedData = selectedOption
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96064/discussion-on-question-by-matty-swift-tableviewcontroller-segue-to-another-tab).